# R: Time series forecast vs Numeric vector forecast

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting

I have projected a time series using:

```
fit    <-  auto.arima(DataInput)
fcast  <-  forecast(fit, h = 12)
```

For `DataInput`, I used 2 types, the first is a normal numeric vector and the second is that exact same vector converted to a time series:

```
DataInput <- ts(DataInput, freq = 12, start = c(2012, 1))
```

However, the forecasts between the 2 data inputs are completely different. I tried simulating data and I did not find a difference between forecasts, so I guess it must be something with my specific dataset. I am completely stumped.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility – the easiest to check, is what happens to your data when you convert it into time series. Can you provide example?

Also, what package auto.arima came from? It’ possible that it uses different default settings for numeric vectors and for time series vectors. I.e. it can set different time lags – annual for time series (since it knows you provided monthly data), but only monthly lags for numeric data. It can introduce seasonal component for the time series, but not for numeric one. Anyhow you have to study documentation. Hope this helps